# Check Laravel Bouncer user roles and permissions to determine if able to login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, roles, laravel-authentication

I'm using standard Laravel authentication and I've added the Joseph Silber Bouncer package to setup roles and abilities. On the login process I would like to check if the user has a specific role or ability. I suspect I can do this here:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

I have added it to this function, but I think there might be a better way, as this is logging them in, checking their roles/abilities and then logging them out.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if($user->cannot('login'))
    {
        \Session::flash('alert-type', 'danger');
        \Session::flash('message', 'Account has Expired');
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Does anyone happen to know of a better way or this acceptable?

Comment: you dont ever modify the files in vendor folder. any update and your code disappears. You need to make a custom middleware or follow the package instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You must not edit files in vendor. You can create custom class inherenting main class in vendor.

You need to create custom login controller file:

create cont²roller using artisan

```
php artisan make:controller LoginController
```

Then in it:

```
LoginController extends Controller
{
  
 use AuthenticatesUsers;

   public function myLogin(Request $request)
   {
    return $this->login($request) ;
    }

 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) 
{ if($user->cannot('login')) 
  { \Session::flash('alert-type', 'danger'); 
    \Session::flash('message', 'Account has 
     Expired'); 
    \Auth::logout(); 
    return redirect('/login'); }
     }
}
```

You need define route

```
Route::post('login','LoginController@myLogin');
```

or if you are using `Auth::routes` :

```
Auth::routes(['login'=>false])  ;
Route::post('login','LoginController@myLogin');
```

Comment: Good solution - it's working. I did notice that I have to have Route::post('login',[LoginController::class, 'login']); before 
Auth::routes(); in my routes/web.php otherwise I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Also, maybe goes without saying but you have to have use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers; in the LoginController

Comment: Actually I made an error in my testing - this solution is not working. If I move the route before the auth::routes then it simply uses the default login controller and not my customized version. The customized version returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I'm able to dd the request on the login function in the custom LoginController but if I try in AuthenticatesUsers I get the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: you can use  `auth::routes(['login' => false]) ` and then add the custom login route before or after it

Comment: I still get the same thing: localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. In my new LoginController I have login public function login which uses AuthenticatesUsers which has a public function login as well. The first function calls $this->login($request); Is that not calling the function within itself as opposed to the one in AuthenticatesUsers?

Comment: I figured out a solution: I copy the contents of the login function from AuthenticatesUsers to my LoginController, thereby overriding it. Hopefully that's correct. I realized that calling return $this->login($request); in the login function was calling itself and likely generating the error.

Comment: try it: change the name login  method  of custom controller. I'll update the answer

Comment: I believe the problem was because of login method calling itself infinitely. you don't need override orginal login method content